# error on creating new object from serialport node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I've check such kind of issue. but i don't find any. if you found it. just let me know.
I just getting started write javascript through node.js, and serialport. cand someone explain me why this error appear?

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homeautomation/server.js:42
var sp = new serialPort(portName, {
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homeautomation/server.js:42:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

this is my starting code

```
/*
 * dependencies
 */
var express = require('express'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    serialPort = require('serialport').serialPort;

server.listen(3000);
console.log('listen on port 3000')

/*
 * Express
 */

var app = express();

// serve static files from index
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});


// respon to web GET request on index.html
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


/*
 * Serial Port Setup
 */

var portName = '/dev/tty.usb.serial-A501JUTF';
//var portName = '/dev/tty.usbmodem1421';
var readData = ''; //Array to hold the values read from the port

var sp = new serialPort(portName, {
    baudRate : 9600,
    dataBits : 8,
    parity : 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl : false,
});
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, except that you used the `serialPort` object of the `require('serialport')` library, when it's in fact `SerialPort` that you need to use, hence the `undefined is not a function` error that you encountered.

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport")
console.log(SerialPort.serialPort); // undefined
console.log(SerialPort.SerialPort); // { [Function: SerialPort, ... }
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#to-use) for a sample usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works perfectly.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var serialPort = SerialPort.serialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", { 
});
```